# How to make aab format support more devices

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-app-bundle

I have an existing app in the play store which is in APK format. I created the next release as `.aab`. When I uploaded the file, the play console shows the message that the release will stop support for over 1000 devices. How can I reduce this number?

`minsdk  19`
`targetsdk 28`

I would also like to mention that I have not edited the `build.gradle` since the last release. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Increase your targetSDK to 29 / 30 , this will add support for newer devices that runs android 9 and up, This will make your app compatible with more devices, NOTE You might need to change certain parts of your app to work with changes brought with the newer SDKs

Comment: @RubenMeiring this is not how targetSdk works.

Comment: +1 to @keyboardsurfer. Have you checked the list of <uses-feature> in the AndroidManifest.xml? Some of the features might be too restrictive?

Comment: @Pierre  I have not added any <uses-feature> but i am sure the Zxing scanner  i am using must have some. How does this affect the .aab file. I don't get this message when building apk file.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer Sorry english is my 3rd language, I was implying that the OP has to make the app compatible with latest android,

Comment: What message? Can you copy it?